# R: How to get common counts (frequency) of levels of two factor variables by ID Variable (as new data frame)

Tags: r, count, frequency

To get the question clear, let me start with one baby example of my data frame.

```
ID <- c(rep("first", 2), rep("second", 4), rep("third",1), rep("fourth", 3))
Var_1 <- c(rep("A",2), rep("B", 2), rep("A",3), rep("B", 2), "A")
Var_2 <- c(rep("C",2), rep("D",3) , rep("C",2),  rep("E",2), "D")

DF <- data.frame(ID, Var_1, Var_2)

> DF
       ID  Var_1 Var_2
1   first     A     C
2   first     A     C
3  second     B     D
4  second     B     D
5  second     A     D
6  second     A     C
7   third     A     C
8  fourth     B     E
9  fourth     B     E
10 fourth     A     D
```

There is one `ID` factor variable and two factor variables `Var_1` with `R=2` factor levels and `Var_2` with `C=3` factor levels.

I would like to get a new data frame with `(RxC)+1=(2x3)+1` Variables with the frequencies of all combinations of factor levels - separately for each level in ID Variable, that would look like this:

```
      ID   A.C  A.D  A.E  B.C  B.D  B.E
1  first    2    0    0    0    0    0
2 second    1    1    0    0    2    0
3  third    1    0    0    0    0    0
4 fourth    0    1    0    0    0    2
```

I tried a couple of functions, but results were not even close to this, so they are not even worth of mentioning. In original data frame I should get (6x9)+1=55 Variables.

EDIT: There are solutions for counting factor levels for one or many variables separatly, but I couldn´t figure it out how to make a common counts for combinations of factor levels for two (or more) variables. Implementig the solution to others seems easy now when I got the answers, but I could not get there by myself.

Comment: ^^Add a parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `dcast` function from the *reshape* package (or *data.table* which has an enhanced implementation of the `dcast` function):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(DF, ID ~ paste(Var_1,Var_2,sep="."), fun.aggregate = length)
```

which gives:

```
      ID A.C A.D B.D B.E
1  first   2   0   0   0
2 fourth   0   1   0   2
3 second   1   1   2   0
4  third   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: The best  solution for my problem here, because it results directly with the data frame.

Comment: Thanx. But I have to mention that the method of @StevenBeaupré will return a dataframe as well.

Comment: True, I missed that. Sorry StevenBeaupré.  His method though seems more individual, which is verry nice and even better choice, if you came yourself to the answer. I still prefer your proposal, because it´s a common used function.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `paste` to create a variable combining Var_1 and Var_2 and then produce a contingency table with ID and the new variable:

```
table(DF$ID,paste(DF$Var_1,DF$Var_2,sep="."))
```

output

```
         A.C A.D B.D B.E
  first    2   0   0   0
  fourth   0   1   0   2
  second   1   1   2   0
  third    1   0   0   0
```

To order the table rows, we would need to `factor(DF$ID,levels=c("first","second","third","fourth"))` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  unite(Var, Var_1, Var_2, sep = ".") %>%
  count(ID, Var) %>%
  spread(Var, n, fill = 0)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#
#      ID   A.C   A.D   B.D   B.E
#  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1  first     2     0     0     0
#2 fourth     0     1     0     2
#3 second     1     1     2     0
#4  third     1     0     0     0
```