# calculate frequency, separate and transpose column that have two factor variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

This is my data https://www.dropbox.com/s/msf0ro8saav7wbl/data1.txt?dl=0 (dataA), i want to extract "Habitat" to have frequency table so that i can calculate any statistical analysis such as mean and variance, and also to plot such as boxplot using ggplot2

I tried to use solution in duplicate question here [R: How to get common counts (frequency) of levels of two factor variables by ID Variable (as new data frame)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131355/r-how-to-get-common-counts-frequency-of-levels-of-two-factor-variables-by-id) but i think it does not help my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the easiest way to get a `data.frame` with frequencies using `table`. I'm using `t` to transpose and `as.data.frame.matrix` to transform it into a `data.frame`.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(data1)))
         A B C
Adult    1 2 1
Juvenile 2 0 0
```

Comment: Hye. i have edited my question. Let say i have big data, dataA here (you can refer my link) and have another subset of data1 that contain "Habitat" how do i transpose and make frequency table